# Exploratory Structural Equation Model (ESEM) in R: Exploratory Specification Model

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling

Thanks in advance for your help.  I have been trying to developed ESEM in R, and am hoping to generate some fit statistics for a 3 factor model.  My data include 12 items and 213 observations.  I pasted the data below the codes/output.  Does anyone know how to specify the model?  I got as far as this by referring to *Using SEM Library in R software to Analyze Exploratory Structural Equation Models* which is a free/open access pdf on the web at http://www.statistics.gov.hk/wsc/CPS105-P6-S.pdf

```
> R.esem1 <- data[,1:12]
> R.Exp11 <- factanal(R.esem1, factors=3)
> R.Exp11

Call:
factanal(x = R.esem1, factors = 3)

Uniquenesses:
V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12 
0.494 0.461 0.364 0.580 0.543 0.301 0.454 0.290 0.476 0.350 0.691 0.415 

Loadings:
Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
V1   0.669  -0.237         
V2  -0.173   0.703   0.125 
V3  -0.165   0.763   0.162 
V4   0.646                 
V5   0.629          -0.228 
V6   0.810          -0.204 
V7   0.693  -0.201  -0.162 
V8   0.780  -0.319         
V9  -0.153   0.115   0.698 
V10  0.795  -0.130         
V11          0.353   0.429 
V12  0.754  -0.130         

                 Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
SS loadings      4.288   1.456   0.838
Proportion Var   0.357   0.121   0.070
Cumulative Var   0.357   0.479   0.548

Test of the hypothesis that 3 factors are sufficient.
The chi square statistic is 70.89 on 33 degrees of freedom.
The p-value is 0.00014 
> F <- matrix(R.Exp11$loadings[1:36],12,3)
> F
         [,1]        [,2]         [,3]
[1,]  0.66932977 -0.23709108 -0.045363582
[2,] -0.17343046  0.70255656  0.124827678
[3,] -0.16488945  0.76301805  0.162456136
[4,]  0.64649603  0.01476361 -0.039659133
[5,]  0.62943270 -0.09518228 -0.228036660
[6,]  0.81009704 -0.03544650 -0.203655807
[7,]  0.69264229 -0.20104671 -0.161732725
[8,]  0.77994820 -0.31877158  0.007721083
[9,] -0.15341745  0.11504193  0.697808969
[10,]  0.79530262 -0.13044749 -0.030411798
[11,] -0.01535601  0.35274568  0.429080759
[12,]  0.75359352 -0.12964507 -0.020748897
> F1 <- rbind(F[1,], F[3,], F[9,])
> F1
       [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
[1,]  0.6693298 -0.2370911 -0.04536358
[2,] -0.1648894  0.7630180  0.16245614
[3,] -0.1534174  0.1150419  0.69780897
> H <- solve(F1) %*% diag (sqrt(diag(F1 %*% t(F1))))
> Rotated.F <- zapsmall (F %*% H)
> Rotated.F
        [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.7115282  0.0000000  0.0000000
[2,] -0.0302663  0.7280160 -0.0263732
[3,]  0.0000000  0.7973563  0.0000000
[4,]  0.7373234  0.2807600 -0.0517021
[5,]  0.6542020  0.1662707 -0.2283677
[6,]  0.8792445  0.3052633 -0.2175721
[7,]  0.7200541  0.0627940 -0.1333875
[8,]  0.8338454 -0.0551906  0.0748016
[9,]  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.7236774
[10,]  0.8811011  0.1720919 -0.0096444
[11,]  0.1476431  0.3570187  0.3793123
[12,]  0.8354451  0.1552792  0.0009104
> solve(H) %*% t(solve(H))
       [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.0000000 -0.5263845 -0.3138709
[2,] -0.5263845  1.0000000  0.3924230
[3,] -0.3138709  0.3924230  1.0000000
> Model.esem1<-specifyModel()
1: F1-> Y1,1am11,.8
2: F1-> Y2,1am41,.7
3: F1-> Y3,1am51,.7
4: F1-> Y4,1am61,.9
5: F1-> Y8,1am71,.7
6: F1-> Y9,1am81,.8
7: F1-> Y10,1am101,.9
8: F1-> Y11,1am111,.1
9: F1-> Y12,1am121,.8
10: F2-> Y2,1am22,.7
11: F2-> Y3,1am32,.8
12: F2-> Y4,1am42,.3
13: F2-> Y5,1am52,.2
14: F2-> Y6,1am62,.3
15: F2-> Y7,1am72,.1
16: F2-> Y8,1am82,.1
17: F2-> Y10,1am102,.2
18: F2-> Y11,1am112,.4
19: F2-> Y12,1am122,.2
20: F3-> Y4,1am43,.1
21: F3-> Y5,1am53,.2
22: F3-> Y6,1am63,.2
23: F3-> Y7,1am73,.1
24: F3-> Y8,1am83,.1
25: F3-> Y9,1am93,.7
26: F3-> Y11,1am113,.4
27: F4-> X,1am133,0
28: F4-> Y1,NA,0
29: F4-> Y2,NA,0
30: F4-> Y3,NA,0
31: F4-> Y4,NA,0
32: F4-> Y5,NA,0
33: F4-> Y6,NA,0
34: F4-> Y7,NA,0
35: F4-> Y8,NA,0
36: F4-> Y9,NA,0
37: F4-> Y10,NA,0
38: F4-> Y11,NA,0
39: F4-> Y12,NA,0
40: F4-> X,1am134,1
41: F1<->F2,NA,.5
42: F1<->F3,NA,.3
43: F2<->F3,NA,.4
44: F1<->F1,NA,1
45: F2<->F2,NA,1
46: F3<->F3,NA,1
47: F4<->F1,NA,1
48: F4<->F2,NA,1
49: F4<->F3,NA,1
50: F4<->F4,NA,1
51: F1<-F4,NA,.5
52: F2<-F4,NA,.5
53: F3<-F4,NA,1
54: 
Read 53 records
NOTE: it is generally simpler to use specifyEquations() or cfa()
  see ?specifyEquations
NOTE: adding 13 variances to the model
> sem.esem1 <- sem(Model.esem1,R.esem1,N=213)
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = obs.variables) : 
'names' attribute [213] must be the same length as the vector [12]

1   4   3   1   3   1   2   3   1   1   3   2
4   2   3   4   5   4   3   5   2   4   2   5
5   1   1   4   4   5   5   5   1   5   4   5
5   1   1   5   5   5   5   5   1   5   5   5
5   1   1   5   5   4   5   3   1   5   1   5
4   3   4   3   3   1   1   2   3   2   1   2
3   4   1   1   2   1   1   3   2   3   1   1
3   3   4   3   3   3   3   3   1   4   2   3
5   1   1   1   5   4   5   4   1   4   1   4
3   1   2   3   4   3   1   4   3   5   1   5
5   1   1   3   3   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
2   5   5   2   1   5   2   1   5   3   4   5
5   5   5   3   4   4   5   4   3   5   4   5
5   3   5   4   5   5   3   3   1   5   3   5
5   1   1   3   1   3   3   5   3   3   1   5
5   3   1   4   5   5   3   2   2   2   1   3
5   1   1   4   5   4   5   5   5   5   1   5
5   2   1   1   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
2   1   1   5   5   5   5   5   1   5   5   5
5   1   2   5   5   5   4   5   1   5   1   5
3   3   1   3   3   2   3   3   2   3   2   4
5   1   1   3   4   4   4   4   1   5   1   4
3   1   1   1   3   1   1   1   4   3   1   1
5   1   1   1   5   4   5   4   1   4   1   4
5   1   1   3   3   3   3   5   1   5   1   5
1   2   5   1   1   1   1   1   5   1   3   1
4   1   1   3   3   3   4   4   3   3   2   4
4   2   1   3   2   3   4   2   4   3   2   3
2   3   4   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   4
3   5   5   1   1   1   2   1   5   1   5   2
5   1   4   3   3   1   1   3   3   5   3   3
4   2   4   3   3   4   4   5   3   3   2   4
1   2   3   1   2   4   4   4   1   5   3   5
3   4   4   3   4   4   5   4   3   4   2   3
4   1   4   3   4   4   1   3   2   1   4   3
5   1   3   5   5   3   5   5   3   5   1   5
5   1   1   1   1   3   5   5   5   3   5   5
5   1   1   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   1   3
4   4   4   4   4   5   3   1   3   3   3   4
4   3   1   5   4   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
1   3   3   3   3   4   4   3   4   5   1   4
5   1   5   3   3   3   2   3   5   5   5   5
3   5   5   2   5   3   1   2   1   5   1   2
5   1   2   5   5   3   5   5   1   5   1   5
4   4   1   4   2   3   4   4   3   4   2   4
4   3   4   4   4   5   1   4   1   3   3   4
3   3   3   4   2   3   2   3   5   5   3   4
3   2   3   2   3   3   4   3   2   2   2   3
4   1   1   4   4   5   5   5   3   5   3   5
4   2   2   2   4   4   4   4   3   4   3   4
3   2   2   3   2   1   2   3   2   2   1   2
1   1   1   1   4   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
5   2   1   4   5   5   2   5   2   2   5   5
3   5   5   4   5   3   1   2   3   4   3   4
5   3   1   5   5   5   5   5   3   5   1   3
5   2   3   3   4   4   5   5   2   5   5   5
4   2   1   4   3   3   3   5   3   3   1   4
5   1   1   5   5   5   3   4   1   5   1   5
5   3   5   3   3   3   3   3   4   2   3   1
1   2   4   5   4   3   1   2   5   5   4   5
5   1   1   3   5   5   5   5   3   5   5   5
5   3   3   5   5   5   1   5   5   5   5   5
3   1   1   3   3   3   3   5   1   4   1   4
3   1   1   3   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
3   5   5   1   1   1   2   1   5   1   5   2
5   1   1   5   5   5   5   5   3   5   2   5
4   2   1   2   2   1   1   3   4   1   1   4
4   5   5   3   5   5   5   4   1   5   2   5
4   1   1   4   4   1   1   4   3   4   1   4
4   1   1   1   4   5   5   3   1   1   1   3
4   1   3   5   3   4   4   4   1   4   1   4
5   2   2   3   3   4   3   3   3   4   3   4
3   3   4   2   5   4   1   2   1   2   2   2
4   2   3   3   3   2   2   3   3   4   2   4
5   1   2   4   5   4   3   5   4   3   2   5
5   1   1   3   5   5   5   5   5   5   1   5
5   1   1   1   1   5   5   5   1   5   3   5
5   1   1   5   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
5   2   2   5   5   3   2   5   1   5   1   5
3   2   3   3   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1
4   5   1   1   1   5   4   1   3   5   1   5
5   2   2   5   4   5   5   4   1   5   1   4
3   3   4   2   5   4   1   2   1   2   2   2
5   2   2   4   5   5   5   5   3   5   2   5
5   3   4   4   5   5   5   5   4   5   1   5
4   1   2   2   2   4   4   3   5   5   3   3
3   2   3   3   1   2   2   3   2   3   2   2
4   3   3   3   5   3   2   3   3   2   2   4
5   2   2   4   5   3   3   4   1   3   2   3
5   2   1   4   5   4   5   4   1   5   1   4
4   3   3   2   3   4   4   3   2   3   3   4
3   1   1   1   3   3   2   2   1   1   1   3
5   1   1   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   1   5
5   1   1   1   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
5   3   3   1   5   5   5   4   3   5   3   5
5   1   1   5   0   5   5   3   3   3   3   3
3   5   5   1   5   5   5   4   5   3   5   5
5   5   4   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   4
5   3   1   2   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
5   1   1   5   5   5   5   4   2   5   2   5
5   1   3   4   3   3   4   4   3   5   2   5
2   1   2   1   3   2   4   2   4   3   3   2
4   2   3   2   3   4   3   4   2   4   2   4
5   3   1   4   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   4
4   1   1   1   4   4   4   4   3   3   3   3
4   1   1   2   4   4   4   4   1   5   2   4
5   3   3   5   5   5   1   5   5   5   5   5
5   1   1   3   3   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
5   1   1   4   4   4   3   4   3   4   2   3
4   3   3   4   3   3   3   4   3   4   3   3
5   5   5   5   5   5   3   3   1   5   5   3
5   1   3   4   3   4   4   4   2   5   1   5
5   3   1   3   2   3   2   3   3   3   3   3
4   3   4   5   5   5   4   5   2   5   1   5
5   3   4   5   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
5   1   1   4   4   3   4   5   4   5   3   5
5   1   1   2   4   4   4   4   1   5   1   5
3   3   2   4   1   3   1   4   2   4   1   2
5   1   1   1   3   5   1   5   1   5   1   5
3   1   1   3   3   3   5   3   1   5   1   3
4   1   1   1   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
5   3   2   3   3   4   4   3   4   4   5   5
5   3   2   5   5   5   5   1   1   5   1   5
5   3   5   4   3   5   4   3   1   2   1   4
5   1   1   5   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
3   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3
5   1   1   5   5   4   4   5   1   5   1   5
3   2   5   1   2   1   1   2   4   2   3   5
5   1   1   5   5   4   4   5   5   5   3   4
5   1   1   3   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
5   1   4   5   3   5   2   5   3   5   5   5
2   4   3   2   1   2   2   3   4   2   2   4
4   4   2   3   3   5   2   4   4   4   2   5
5   1   1   3   3   3   3   3   2   3   1   4
3   1   1   3   4   3   3   3   3   3   3   5
5   5   1   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   3   5
5   4   3   2   3   3   1   4   4   2   2   5
3   1   1   3   3   4   4   4   1   5   1   4
3   2   1   2   4   5   5   3   1   5   1   5
3   4   3   1   1   3   1   3   1   4   2   5
4   1   3   4   4   3   4   5   2   5   1   5
5   1   1   3   5   5   3   5   1   5   3   5
5   2   2   2   3   4   4   3   2   5   1   5
4   3   1   3   3   3   3   4   3   3   1   4
5   1   1   1   4   2   1   3   3   4   1   3
2   5   2   1   1   1   1   1   5   1   1   1
5   3   4   4   4   4   1   5   3   5   3   5
2   5   4   1   1   2   3   4   4   5   5   1
4   5   5   4   4   3   2   2   4   5   2   3
4   1   1   1   4   1   1   1   1   1   1   5
1   3   1   1   2   3   1   2   5   3   3   1
5   2   5   5   5   5   5   5   2   5   3   5
3   2   3   2   2   2   2   3   3   2   2   2
5   3   2   3   2   4   5   5   4   4   1   3
2   4   5   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1
1   3   4   1   1   1   1   1   5   1   4   3
5   1   1   4   5   5   3   5   1   5   1   5
4   1   1   5   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
1   5   5   2   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   3
5   1   1   5   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
4   3   3   4   3   4   4   4   3   3   3   3
4   3   1   1   4   4   4   4   1   4   4   4
2   3   4   1   1   1   1   1   5   1   4   1
3   3   2   4   4   4   4   4   2   4   4   3
4   2   3   4   4   4   5   4   3   4   3   4
5   2   4   4   4   5   5   4   2   5   3   5
3   3   1   3   3   5   4   4   3   5   2   5
3   2   5   4   3   3   4   5   3   5   1   5
1   5   5   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   5   1
4   5   5   5   3   4   5   5   2   5   3   5
5   5   5   3   3   3   3   3   3   4   1   3
1   5   5   1   4   3   2   2   5   3   1   3
4   5   5   5   4   5   3   4   2   5   4   5
3   1   5   3   4   2   1   2   2   2   3   2
5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   2   5   3   5
1   3   5   3   3   3   1   2   3   5   3   5
4   5   5   3   2   4   4   3   2   4   2   5
4   2   4   3   3   4   2   3   4   4   2   3
4   2   3   2   3   4   5   4   3   4   5   4
5   2   2   1   3   3   3   4   4   5   1   4
3   5   1   3   3   5   5   5   3   5   3   5
4   1   1   2   3   4   4   4   1   4   1   5
5   1   2   5   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   4
1   3   4   1   1   1   1   1   5   1   4   3
3   2   2   3   2   1   1   3   2   5   5   3
5   1   1   5   5   4   5   5   1   5   1   5
5   5   4   3   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
3   4   4   1   1   4   4   2   2   3   4   3
5   3   4   4   1   4   3   2   3   4   3   5
2   5   5   1   5   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
4   3   4   3   4   3   1   4   5   5   5   5
3   4   4   1   1   2   1   1   3   2   5   2
5   2   1   5   5   5   5   4   1   5   1   5
5   1   3   5   5   5   5   5   2   5   2   5
4   4   5   3   4   2   1   2   4   2   4   3
2   1   4   1   2   3   4   5   3   2   4   5
3   2   3   4   4   4   4   3   3   4   3   4
4   4   4   3   3   2   3   3   3   3   4   4
5   3   1   5   5   4   5   5   4   5   5   5
3   4   1   1   3   1   1   4   5   2   2   1
2   5   1   1   1   4   1   2   2   1   5   3
1   1   2   2   3   2   2   2   2   3   1   4
5   1   2   3   5   5   3   5   3   5   3   5
5   2   2   5   5   5   5   5   1   5   1   5
3   2   1   2   4   3   3   5   4   3   2   3
5   5   5   5   4   4   4   5   1   4   5   5
5   5   5   3   3   2   3   4   5   4   2   5
5   1   1   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   1   5
5   2   4   1   4   1   5   5   5   5   1   2
2   3   4   3   3   3   3   2   3   2   3   4
3   5   4   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1
3   3   3   2   3   1   1   1   5   1   3   1
2   3   4   2   1   1   2   1   2   3   5   1
```

Comment: The data did not paste so well.  Again, there are only 12 items.  So, the first observation is the following: 1 4 3 1 3 1 2 3 1 1 3 2.

Comment: What do you get when you try? What's the problem?

Comment: I get this, and I am not sure what to do next.
'> Model.esem1<-specifyModel()
1:'

Comment: I tried to find the PDF you're referring to--what's the URL?

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe thanks for the response, here is the URL http://www.statistics.gov.hk/wsc/CPS105-P6-S.pdf

Comment: Yves Rosseel and I invested a lot to figure out how to flexibly estimate ESEMs including standard errors for the rotated parameters. From version 0.6-4, lavaan is able to fit a range of ESEM models (beta version).